# Unsigned integer type in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

Java designer's felt that unsigned integers were unnecessary. Specifically, they felt that  the concept of unsigned was used mostly to specify the behavior of the high-order bit, which defines the sign of an integer value. Java manages the meaning of the high-order bit differently, by adding a special "Unsigned Right Shift Operator >>>". Thus, the need for an unsigned integer type was eliminated. Then, why Java 8 will have some support for unsigned integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For the first cut, I've favored keeping the code straightforward over 
>   trickier but potentially faster algorithms.  Tests need to be written 
>   for the unsigned divide and remainder methods, but otherwise the 
>   regression tests are fairly extensive.
>
> To avoid the overhead of having to deal with boxed objects, the
>   unsigned  functionality is implemented as static methods on Integer
>   and Long, etc.  as opposed to introducing new types like
>   UnsignedInteger and UnsignedLong.

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2012-January/008926.html

Also refer this : https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/unsigned_api

Answer (score 4):

Java 8 includes just some helper methods (static methods on java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long) that implement commonly needed operations.

Most of them are quite trivial *if* you know http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement, *but* as experience shows *many* programmers have struggled (as is evident by the number of related questions of SO) to arrive at those simple solutions for these operations.

There is no magical difference between a signed and an unsigned int, viewed as bit patterns signed and unsigned look the same. The difference lies in the interpretation of said patterns. Its relatively simple to emulate any unsigned operation using signed types, so unsigned types are not an absolutely necessary language element to perform unsigned arithmetic.

In short: There are no unsigned types in Java8 because it would be a huge effort to add them (if there were primitives it would require also large additions to the bytecode and JLS).

There are some helper methods because thats what is commonly needed and hard to get right (for the average joe developer).

Comment: Why do you say that adding unsigned types to the Java *language* would require *bytecode* changes when you say yourself that there is no real difference between the data types besides *interpreting* them? See, `int` is *signed* and `char` is *unsigned* and `boolean` something completely different but all three are handled with the same data type on byte code level. It’s all about how to interpret the data.

Comment: @Holger I wouldn't entirely rule out that unsigned types could be added purely on the compiler level, but that would mean that certain operations would have to be implemented in quite a roundabout manner (especially the comparison operators >, >=, <, <=). While its about *how* data is interpreted, part of the interpretation is done on the bytecode level (if-type bytecodes).

Comment: These operations could be compiled by generating method calls to the `static` methods that have been added in Java 8. It’s not unusual that an operator creates method calls behind the scenes, see `+` for `String`s. However, the *language* changes would be indeed big and counter-intuitive (e.g. array length/index had to remain signed for compatibility reasons)

Comment: @Holger You're right, in principle there are no operations that could not be implemented by having the compiler generate method calls. I personally would call that a rather half-assed implementation, but in terms of the language smenatics it wouldn't matter one bit. Considering java's already rather odd treatment of operations on types smaller than int (the implicit widening to int is good for a few WTFs), I'm not even sure I ever want to see unsigned primitives :)